# Regular expression error in python : sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to return `True` only if a letter has a `+` before and after it

```
def SimpleSymbols(string): 
if re.search(r"(?<!+)\w(?!+)", string) is None :
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: `+` is a special character in regular expressions, you need to escape it.

Comment: you have to escape the `+` which is a quantifier

Comment: But `\w` does not match just letters. Use `def SimpleSymbols(string): return re.search(r"\+[^\W\d_]\+", string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unescaped `+` is a quantifier that repeats the pattern it modifies 1 or more times. To match a literal `+`, you need to escape it.

However, the `(?<!\+)` and `(?!\+)` will do the opposite: they will fail the match if a char is preceded or followed with `+`.

Also, `\w` does not match just letters, it matches letters, digits, underscore and with Unicode support in Python 3.x (or with `re.U` in Python 2.x) even more chars. You may use `[^\W\d_]` instead.

Use

```
def SimpleSymbols(string): 
    return bool(re.search(r"\+[^\W\d_]\+", string))
```

It will return `True` if there is  a `+[Letter]+` inside a string, or `False` if there is no match.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Z68ssW):

```
import re

def SimpleSymbols(string): 
    return bool(re.search(r"\+[^\W\d_]\+", string))
print(SimpleSymbols('+d+dd')) # True
print(SimpleSymbols('ddd'))   # False
```